# Send image in attachments by URL in Circuit JS SDK

Tags: circuit-sdk

I'm using a Circuit JS SDK and want to send message with attached image. I found on documentation that I should set the item.attachments to File[] object. But how can I do it if I have only image URL (like https://abc.cde/fgh.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to post an image in a conversation, the image needs to be uploaded to Circuit which is done internally in the `addTextItem` API as you already found out. And yes this API takes an array of `File` objects.

You will need to download the image via XMLHttpRequest as blob and then construct a File object.

```
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.open('GET',<url of image> , true);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = async () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
      const file = new File([xhr.response], 'image.jpg', { lastModified: Date.now() });
      const item = await client.addTextItem(convId.value, { 
        attachments: [file]
      });
    }
  };

  xhr.send();
```

Here is a jsbin https://output.jsbin.com/sumarub